# ip6tables - configuration

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall

I'm creating another thread for my ip6tables config.

```
ip6tables -F
ip6tables -X
ip6tables -t nat -F
ip6tables -t nat -X
ip6tables -t mangle -F
ip6tables -t mangle -X
ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP 

# Autorise les connexions déjà établies et localhost                
ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT       
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT                          
#ip6tables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT


#TOR
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT

# ICMP (Ping)                                       
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT                      
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT

# DNS                                           
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT                 
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT                     

# HTTP                                          
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT             


#HTTPS
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT                        


# Mail SMTP 

ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25  -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT  
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT


#Transmission
ip6tables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 51413 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 51413 -j ACCEPT


# NTP (horloge du serveur) 
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT    

# On log les paquets en entrée.
ip6tables -A INPUT -j LOG


exit 0
```

Everything works... except smtp. I just don't understand why. Can you please help me understand what's happening ?

Thanks in advance !
    `

Comment: Thanks. But as indicated in said article "A much better idea would be to remove all the -A INPUT ... --sport rules and use just this single rule instead:
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT". I did that. And my iptables was working without any --sport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as recommended, if it can be of help in the future.

For ipv6, icmp is far more important than for ipv4. As such, it need to be allowed.

So, i just had to accept all icmpv6 and everything worked fine.

However, it is apparently not totally secure. The more secured option is to only accept the icmpv6 types that are strictly necessary for everything to work :

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type router-advertisement -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-advertisement -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-solicitation -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type router-solicitation -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-advertisement -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type neighbour-solicitation -m state --state UNTRACKED -m hl --hl-eq 255 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j DROP
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 -j DROP
```